# jquery.ui.datepicker.css CDN Library Url

Tags: jquery, url, cdn

In my Project I'm using jquery.ui.datepicker.css locally.
I need CDN url for jquery.ui.datepicker.css file. Please help me.

Comment: google internet for: "CDN jquery.ui.datepicker.css"

Comment: And Also CDN url for jquery-ui.css

Answer (score 0):

Check this website https://code.jquery.com/ui/ and pick the theme and version you want to use. That URL will take you to the corresponding CSS which already/also includes datepicker.css.